# Can I put animation/effect on div resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

**Objective**: Animate div on content resize.

**Given**:

1. Div height and width are not specified.
2. Div size depends on content size.
3. When content size changes, div size also changes (*without animation, resizes within 0.5FPS*).

**Question:** How do I apply animation/effect on div when it is dynamically changing size, depending on content?

NOTE: one good example of this is @[gmail](http://gmail.com) (card resizes on successful next)

Comment: I think a good place to start would be with the jQuery resize event (https://api.jquery.com/resize/).

Comment: i am not confirm, but i think you can't do with css, the transition is not apply on auto element you have to specify some specific width/height or max width/height. may be some javascript will help  like https://jsfiddle.net/eugf4rzw/

Answer (score 1):

There is a way for this. You need to use a one hidden element for that way. You have to set the content in both elements. try the following

HTML:

`<span id="hiddenElement"></span>`

`<div id="displayElement"></div>`

CSS:

```
#hiddenElement
{
    max-width: 200px;
    opacity: 0;
    /* use different properties to completely hide. but do not give width:0 */
}

#displayElement
{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s; /* Safari */
    transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

JS method:

```
function setContent(content)
{
     $("#hiddenElement").text(content);
     $("#displayElement").text(content);
     $("#displayElement").width($("#hiddenElement").width());
     $("#displayElement").height($("#hiddenElement").height());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply a max-height and a max-width and a display property of inline-block.

```
div {
 display: inline-block;
 background:red;
 transition: max-height 1s, max-width 1s; 
 max-height:0;
 max-width:0;
}
div:hover {
 max-height:200px;
 max-width:400px;
}

<div>yada yada yada</div>
```

Comment: I had encountered this solution. but it does only work on hover and not on content size @partypete